# MS Outlook 2019 can't select from drop down menu options

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office

I have a new Intel NUC kit i7 NUC10i7FNK with a dual monitor setting (4K both, one plugged in via display port and the second via hdmi). Using Windows 10 PRO and MS Office Home and Business 2019 (64-bit).

I have all the latest drivers installed for the NUC and all available updates for Windows/Office.

With Outlook I have a very strange problem. When writing a new email (or replying to one) one of the following happens:

1. I can't click anything from the menu (Message, Insert, Options ...). I mean the menus are there, but it's like they are disabled. Also, I can't change any of the text in the message body window - like it's read only. Only thing responding to mouse clicks are From/To/Cc/Bcc/Subject fields and Send button.

or

2. Everything works, but for the "submenus" in the ribbon. For example, I can click on the Message menu and then click on Signatures drop down in the ribbon. All available signatures are shown, but I can’t click on any. Again, like they are disabled.

or

3. Everything works, but for the message body. Like it's entire "textbox" is read only. Can't select, change or add text

or

4. sometimes everything just works. None of the problems above. Let's say 1/3 of the times I write a new message or reply to one.

I tried removing Office completely and tried installing a 32-bit version, but the same problems remain.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Before going further, please make sure you have fully updated your Outlook and Windows to the latest version.

There could be some add-ins in your Outlook client that cause this issue, so it is suggested to start your Outlook in safe mode (Press Win + R, type “outlook /safe”, press Enter.) and see if the issue continues.

By the way, maybe you could also try to turn on or off the "Disable Hardware Graphics Acceleration In Outlook" and restart Outlook to see if the issue has any difference.

Comment: on the updates: see my post. As for the add-ins and graphics acceleration it was one of the first things I tried, but with no avail.

Comment: Tried some search but have not found similar issues yet. Does this issue only happen to Outlook? Can other Office programs such as Word or Excel work fine without any issues? Besides, since you mentioned that sometimes everything just works, at these specific "sometimes ", have you noticed any other factors(third party programs or windows serivces) which might cause this issue? Trying a clean windows reboot and only run Outlook alone can help exclude some possible factors. 
  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-perform-a-clean-boot-in-windows-da2f9573-6eec-00ad-2f8a-a97a1807f3dd

Comment: No problems with other Office programs. Just Outlook. I'm thinking maybe it's hardware related, because I'm experiecing some on/off problem with secondary display in general. Also, random restarts/crashes of both Visual Studio and SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: Yeap, hardware is also an angle to troubleshoot this issue. If you got More discoveries, please feel free to share with us here.